# compare 2 values in c always return false

Tags: c

i make a simple program to prove a right triange , then i'm using `pow`function to multiple the input like ;

```
if(pow(c,2) == (pow(a,2) + pow(b,2))){
   printf("True.");
}else{
   printf("False.");
}
```

then i entered the value to `a = 3, b = 4, c = 5` , it should be true because `25 == 25`
but it returned a false,

but if i change the code to this :

```
if((c*c) == ((a*a) + (b*b))){
   printf("True.");
}else{
   printf("False.");
}
```

the result is true

nb : `input is a double`

any explanation of this error ? thank you

Comment: Your first example with `a = 3, b = 4, c = 5` printed `True` to me...

Comment: There are dozens of questions and answers about this.  Search for floating point comparison.

Comment: oke thank you and sorry because i dont know the keyword @RetiredNinja

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pow(x, y)` is normally implemented as `exp(y log x)`. This can go off for even seemingly trivial values of the arguments.

You are seeing the effect of this.

There's no hard and fast rule for dealing with floating point precision issues. Comparing with a tolerance is often mooted as a solution but picking the level of tolerance or the way it ought to be applied is not in itself trivial.

In your case it would be best to compare `a * a + b * b` with `c * c;` particularly if these are always integral values.